# Bootstrap navbar not appearing on mobile

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

The navbar works fine when the window is full sized but when the window is resized or when looking at the site on mobile, the navbar disappears and just shows a small strip with no links in it.

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="ResumeKJ.pdf">Resume</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways yo solve this, the first one is let the `navbar` expanded all the time using `navbar-expand` in replacement of `navbar-expand-lg`:

**Example 1:**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="ResumeKJ.pdf">Resume</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The second way is to add the code that support the collapsed mode of the navbar ([Read more here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/)), but you just need to add the button that will toggle the collapsed navbar:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
```

**Example 2:**

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="ResumeKJ.pdf">Resume</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing both `navbar-brand` which is optional but shows on the right, and `navbar-toggle` which displays the button to expand the navbar; also remember to add an `id` to the collapse section to reference

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" id="navbar">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact Me</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="ResumeKJ.pdf">Resume</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```